# Ubuntu won't boot after switch to nvidia graphics

Tags: 16.04, boot, drivers, nvidia

I've installed nvidia-390 driver and switched to it using alternative drivers in  dash. Now my system boots to the black screen. I was able to boot to tty and gain root privileges. How do i switch back to intel graphics to boot my PC?

P.S. I've tried `sudo prime-select intel` but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Purge all *nvidia* packages. Remove the blacklist-nvidia conf so that nouveau will load, and then work from there.